# OAuth 2.0 сервер

Tags: oauth, php

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с задачей создания API для одного неизвестного ресурса :) Решил, что велосипед изобретать не стоит.... и не стоит особо возиться с написанием всяких либок.

Вобщем, решил использовать OAuth 2.0 библиотеку, но описания к установке для сервера не нашел, да и так... мало что нашел по этому поводу в гугле (гуглю с 2.00 ночи)...

Если кто-нибудь уже работал с сием чудом и успешно сумел им воспользоваться, напишите, пожалуйста, откуда брали серверную часть (на PHP) этого OAuth 2.0 сервера и документацию для его установки :)

Очень благодарен :)

P.S. Ссылка типо "http://oauth.net" - не считается. Там как-то все расплывчато :(

Comment: а какой именно вы исходник сервера вы качали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос можно считать закрытым.
Потребовалось: 
 1. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth
 2. 4 часа времени

Скачивать, разбираться и запиливать под себя вышло бы дороже и не факт, что более адекватно и правильно.

Answer (score 2):

[Как бе намекаю](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/oauth/trunk/examples/) на самом сайте есть [ссылочка](http://oauth.net/code/)